# iOS Autolayout: Is the Size Constrains for UIView is Obligatory?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard

I am trying to arrange controls in the storyboard using constrains via Interface Builder ("Any Width, Any Height" case). I add there UIView, however, when I press update frames for this element (Selected Views case) according to the given constrains UIView disappears from my view. I guess it size becomes zero. Later on, it is not show up in the screen after the run. The issue is also reported in the issue navigator: Horizontal Position of UIView is ambiguous (marked with the green shape). Anyway, if I set the constrain for width or height (size parameters) together with the constrain of ratio, then the issue disappears, I can update frames, it shows up in the screen during the run.

I am adding the picture with the green marks to make the issue more clear:

[image]

1. The question is whether the parameters of the size are obligatory when I am setting the constrains.
2. Even if they are obligatory how I can make the size to fit different sizes of the screens or iPhone+iPad because if I set/fix the size it could too big for some screens.

Answer (score 1):

The size is not mandatory. The warning tells you that you must set an X position for this view (constraint between the superView left or right border and the left / right border of the view itself). If you want the view to resize itself to fit each screen size you must set both left and right constraint without the size constraint.

Comment: But if I do not set the size constrain, then I cannot Update Frames without loosing it from the view.

Comment: Note: If you set constraints on one view, you must do so for all views (notwithstanding the primary view of the view controller).  Also, those warnings about ambiguous constraints are important-- don't ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't used fixed size (width or height) for view that change size when screen dimension change.

If you want view that fix aspect ratio you can set size that relative to Superview's width or height using:

1) leading and trailing and make sure that

```
    view.leading = superview.leading + fixed_margin
    view.trailing = superview.trailing - fixed_margin
```

and not other way around.

2) equal width or equal height with multiplier, constant relative to superview as you want

So you don't need evil size class.